# fp growth algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

I have to implement [FP-growth algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#FP-growth_algorithm) using any language.  The code should be a serial code with no recursion.  Is it possible to implement such algorithm without recursion?  I am not looking for code, I just need an explanation of how to do it.

Comment: How is your question related to C#, C, C++, or Java? What is an "fp growth algorithm"? I'll improve your tags. Mihran answer captures almost everything which could be said to your rather unspecific and general question. If you're interested in more information, please improve your question.

Comment: its because i can implement the algorithm with any of these languages..

Comment: But then, why did you not add python, ruby, lisp, haskell, etc.?

Comment: Don't spam tags please.  This isn't a relevant question to the people following the C family of tags.

Answer (score 12):

FPGrowth is a recursive algorithm. Like some other people said here, you can always transform an algorithm into a non recursive algorithm by using a stack.  But I don't see any good reasons to do that for FPGrowth.

By the way, if you want a Java implementation of FPGrowth and other frequent pattern mining algorithms such as Apriori, HMine, Eclat, etc., you can check my website. I have implemented more than 40 algorithms for frequent pattern mining, association rule mining, etc.:

http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/

Comment: That's impressive, great job!

Comment: thanks Phil, i found your algorithms library  from your comment here,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the algorithm you talking about. But everyting what is possible with recursion it is possible also without it. You can implement such kind of algorithms using stack.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://hareenlaks.blogspot.com/2011/06/fp-tree-example-how-to-identify.html) is an very clear explanation of how the code works. It looks like you have to build a tree and validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "FP growth Algorithm" you mean frequent Pattern growth algorithm, I would point you over to this document that gives a decent explanation on how it works.

http://www.florian.verhein.com/teaching/2008-01-09/fp-growth-presentation_v1%20%28handout%29.pdf

I wonder though, is this homework related?

Comment: yes it is HW related.but i am not seeking solution or code, i need some recommendations so i continue with the project or change the topic and choose another algorithm to implement...

Answer (score -1):

You can probably visit http://code.google.com/p/lofia/ to get something over FP Tree.
This is for longest frequent itemset mining.

Answer (score -1):

You can take look at the concept & implemenntation FP growth algoithm in Mahout